# iOS6 device only. UITableView disappears off screen when making a call to sqlite and returning from a UINavigation

Tags: c#, sqlite, uitableview, xamarin.ios, ios6

My iPhone app (developed using c# and monotouch) has worked fine on iOS5. Since the upgrade to iOS6, I am experiencing the following problem: (NOTE: only occurs on device, not simulator)

My first page is a UITableView. If you select a row, it takes you to another view. This view queries the database (SQLite) to load further information based on the selected incidentId.

When I click the UINavigation Back button to go back to my first page, the UITable view disappears off screen.

When I scroll anywhere on the screen, the UITableView reappears and performs as expected.

After going through code line by line, I've narrowed it down to one line of code, being
cmd.ExecuteReader (cmd being SqliteConnection > CreateCommen() > ExecuteReader() )

If I remove that line of code and hardcode in the object result, the UITableView works normally.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Its only doing this on iOS 6 on the device ONLY. The simulator with iOS6 works normally.

Comment: this is going to depend a lot on the specfifics, try to create a small self-contained case that shows your program flow

Answer (score 0):

Does `cmd.ExecuteReader` return valid results? Sounds like it may be returning an empty result  set which means no results can be displayed.